# Custom translator - Model training fail and small "used sentence" than expection

Tags: microsoft-translator, machine-translation

I uploaded my documents (bilingual documents) which include more than 13,000 sentences. 
But the training result is... only 60% of sentences have been aligned and 40% of sentences have been used for training. So, only 5000 sentences are used.

1. When I uploaded, I used one bilingual files for source file and target file. 
   Is this problem caused by the low number of sentences aligned & used? 
   these files are actually the result of the translation by human.
2. How many sentences should  be used to success training normally?
3. If I success the training, normally, how is the quality compared to google machine translation?

Comment: As far as I know, it's normal that some sentences are split out for tuning and testing.